# Mapping a union type according to a field

Tags: typescript

I have a union type and each subtype has a "type" field. I want to automatically build a type whose fields are the different values of "type", and the values are respectively arrays of the corresponding subtype. Don't know if this is clear, but this example will help :

```js
// What I have :

type A = { type: "A" };
type B = { type: "B" };
type C = { type: "C" };
type MyUnion = A | B | C;

// What I want automatically generated :

type Keyed = {
  A: A[];
  B: B[];
  C: C[];
};
```

Is there a way to do that ***without*** manually mapping "A" to type `A`, etc., given only `MyUnion` ?

I thought of something like :

```js
type Keyed = {
  [T in MyUnion["type"]]: ??
};
```

But then I don't know how to "split" `MyUnion` in individual subtypes based on `T`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is the way to do it:

```js
type Keyed<T extends MyUnion> = {
    [P in T["kind"]]: T extends (infer U)
        ? T["kind"] extends P
            ? U[] : never
        : never
}
```

but it's pretty convoluted. Maybe it's more readable to just write `Keyed` class manually.

Chained `extends` statements are needed, because you want to unsure that you don't have mix of different types in the array. For example, compiler will warn you about this, because you have "A" and "B" types in "A" array:

```js
var c: Keyed<MyUnion> = {
    "A": [{ kind: "A" }, { kind: "B" }], // Error on 2nd item, bacause "B"
    "B": [{ kind: "B" }],
    "C": []
}
```

This is valid data:

```js
var c: Keyed<MyUnion> = {
    "A": [{ kind: "A" }, { kind: "A" }],
    "B": [{ kind: "B" }],
    "C": []
}
```

I renamed property `type` to `kind`. It conforms to the convention in the TypeScript documentation and avoids confusion of using keyword `type` for property name.

Comment: This indeed works just great, thank you. May I ask you to go a bit into details ? What exactly is happening with `infer U` ? Why does your trick work ?

Comment: Sure. `infer U` narrows from `A | B | C` (which would allow to mix types in array) to one of those 3 types at the time. So prevents `"A": MyUnion[]` and makes it `"A": A[]"`

Comment: Okay. When I substitute `T` directly with `MyUnion`, the keys are mapped to `never`. Why is that ? Other question : Why `T["kind"] extends P` and not `U["kind"] extends P` ? Thanks.

Comment: That's a lot of question. It's mainly about syntax. `P` needs union by definition to iterate over it. So it needs "A" | "B" | "C" as input to loop over. Right? Secondly, you cannot put `infer` on the left side of mapping expression. Similar for `T["kind"]` it refers to type variable from `<T>`. `MyUnion` referes to the type declared elsewhere that could or could not be related to `T`. So...